# Обновление текста в div'е?

Tags: jquery, html, javascript, обновление

Собственно вопрос, можно ли как-то обновлять текст, который находится к примеру в div'е (id="textup") через 10 секунд. .get и .load не подходит. Пример: В общем у меня есть часы. На сервере они обновляются постоянно, но на сайте нет. Когда я страницу обновляю, время обновляется, то есть было 12:30, прошла минута если станицу не обновляли, то часы как показывали 12:30 так и показывают (не зависимо от того сколько минут прошло), а когда обновили страницу, время показывает: 12:31, так вот, мне нужно чтобы div просто сам обновлялся (только через js).

Comment: Тогда ответный вопрос - откуда будете брать обновленный контент?

Comment: Написал бы хороший JS но нерасположен я сегдня к этому)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно. Вот способ на JavaScript`е:

```
function updator() {
    var upd_div = document.getElemrntById("textup");
    var now = new Date();
    upd_div.innerHTML = String(now);
}
window.setInterval("updator()", 10000);
```

Comment: В общем у меня есть часы. На сервере они обновляются постоянно, но на сайте нет. Когда я страницу обновляю, время обновляется, то есть было 12:30, прошла минута если станицу не обновляли, то часы как показывали 12:30 так и показывают (не зависимо от того сколько минут прошло), а когда обновили страницу, время показывает: 12:31, так вот, мне нужно чтобы div просто сам обновлялся (только через js).

Comment: Так это только на JS И можно реализовать! AJAX - асинхронный javascript.

Comment: Дополнил ответ

Comment: Благодарю.

Comment: Всегда Пожалуйста =)